# Circuitikz: Change distance of voltage arrow label, locally use straight voltage arrows

Tags: circuitikz

I created a nice little MOSFET model (feel free to use), but two things are not working the way that I want:

1. I want U_GS and U_GD to have straight voltage arrows
2. As you can see, the voltage label interferes with the capacitance. I tried to change the distance of the label using voltage/distance = x (like it works with current/distance) but it gave me an error.

Thanks for your help :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx,fetbodydiode,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[nigfete](mosfet){}
(mosfet.G) to[short,-o] ++ (-1.5,0) coordinate[label=left:G](G)
(mosfet.S) to[short,-o] ++ (0,-1.5) coordinate[label=below:S](S)
(mosfet.D) to[short,-o] ++ (0,1.5) coordinate[label=D] (D)
    (G) ++ (.5,0) coordinate (Gx)
    (S) ++ (0,.5) coordinate (Sx)
    (D) ++ (0,-.5) coordinate (Dx)
    (Gx |- Dx) coordinate (GD)
    (Gx) to [C,l=$C_{GD}$,*-] (GD) to[short,-*] (Dx)
    (Gx |- Sx) coordinate (GS)
    (Gx) to [C,l_=$C_{GS}$,*-] (GS) to[short,-*] (Sx)
    (Dx) --++ (1.5,0) coordinate(D2)
    (Sx) --++ (1.5,0) coordinate(S2)
    (D2) to[C,l=$C_{DS}$] (S2)
    (Gx) to[open,v^=$U_{GR}$] (Dx)
;
\end{circuitikz}




  \caption[Ersatzschaltbild]{Ersatzschaltbild}
  \label{fig:ersatzschaltbild}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the circuits, but I now that you can use ordinary Ti*k*Z commands if you don't like the predefined shapes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx,fetbodydiode,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{label/align = smart}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[nigfete](mosfet){}
(mosfet.G) to[short,-o] ++ (-1.5,0) coordinate[label=left:G](G)
(mosfet.S) to[short,-o] ++ (0,-1.5) coordinate[label=below:S](S)
(mosfet.D) to[short,-o] ++ (0,1.5) coordinate[label=D] (D)
    (G) ++ (.5,0) coordinate (Gx)
    (S) ++ (0,.5) coordinate (Sx)
    (D) ++ (0,-.5) coordinate (Dx)
    (Gx |- Dx) coordinate (GD)
    (Gx) to [C,l=$C_{GD}$,*-] (GD) to[short,-*] (Dx)
    (Gx |- Sx) coordinate (GS)
    (Gx) to [C,l_=$C_{GS}$,*-] (GS) to[short,-*] (Sx)
    (Dx) --++ (1.5,0) coordinate(D2)
    (Sx) --++ (1.5,0) coordinate(S2)
    (D2) to[C,l=$C_{DS}$] (S2)
    (Gx) edge [-latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] node[pos=0.7,sloped,above] {$U_{GR}$} (Dx)
    (Gx) edge [-latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] node[pos=0.6,sloped,above] {$U_{GR}$} (Sx)
;
\end{circuitikz}

  \caption[Ersatzschaltbild]{Ersatzschaltbild}
  \label{fig:ersatzschaltbild}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please don't grill me if the directions of the arrows don't make sense! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hm not quite happy with the result, I'll just leave the arrows for now. It should be already apparent because of my labels D, G and S-

Comment: @SF6 If you tell me how the arrows should look like, they can be adjusted.